# Convert text to time with time zone

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Recieve time in next formats:

`17:42:40 GMT+0300 (EEST)`

`16:42:40 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

`12:42:40 GMT-0200 (WGST)`

How to convert this text to **time with timezone** `17:42:40+3` type for inserting it to table column with such type.

Comment: Investigate Python's **datetime** library, and the methods `strftime()` and `strptime()`: [Basic date and time types: trftime() and strptime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Nice. But i am DB developer. 
And i receive such imput parameter format to my procedure in postgre database.

Comment: Ah I see. Please add that context to your question. I was in a Python mindset :)

Comment: any more samples?.. otherwise `select replace('17:42:40 GMT+0300 (EEST)','00 (EEST)','')::timetz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found better result for all possible cases.

```
SELECT regexp_matches('17:42:40 GMT+0300 (EEST)', 
'[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} GMT[+|-]{1}[0-9]{2}')::text::timetz;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t=# select replace('17:42:40 GMT+0300 (EEST)','00 (EEST)','')::timetz;
   replace
-------------
 17:42:40-03
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names,
>   positive offsets are used for locations **west** of Greenwich. Everywhere
>   else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive
>   timezone offsets are **east** of Greenwich.

also you probably would want to transform TZ to hour:minute form ignoring the value in brackets:

```
t=# select '17:42:40 GMT+03:00'::timetz;
   timetz
-------------
 17:42:40-03
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks. 
Tried `select replace('17:42:40 GMT+0300 (EEST)','00 (EEST)','')::timetz;` 

Cant understand why time changes to `16:42:40 -03:00` result.

Comment: but I posted the link with explanations :)

Comment: Your answer helped me to find better way for this case. 
Time can be of any timezone, not only `EEST`

So in case of next situations:
`17:42:40 GMT+0300 (EEST)`
`16:42:40 GMT+0200 (CEST)`
`12:42:40 GMT-0200 (WGST)`

I see better use next
`SELECT regexp_matches('17:42:40 GMT+0300 (EEST)', '[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} GMT[+|-]{1}[0-9]{2}')::text::timetz;`

Comment: I am sorry. But i still cant understand. 
Why if i use your example `select '17:42:40 GMT+03:00'::timetz;`
I get as result `16:42:40 -03:00`

In your example you get same time.